# html5 img not displayed in gedit

Tags: html, image

I am trying to learn HTML5 and I wrote a code in html to display the image.

Here is the code snippet:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <title>imageDemo.html</title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>This is Pacman Ghost</h1>
        <p>
        <img src="Pacman.png" alt="Pacman Ghost" />
        </p>
    </body>
</html>
```

My image Pacman.png is on the desktop and my test.html file is also on the desktop. I am using gedit in ubuntu 14.04 to write the code. When i run my file test.html, I don't see the image but see Pacman Ghost as text.

What am I doing wrong here??

Hope to hear soon from you guys.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You wrote that you image is on the desktop. You use an relative path. So the best way is to make a folder and put all your files in that folder.

Your code looks correct but i think your your image is in the wrong place.

And you should have a look at the case sensitivity of your file.

Use the debug bar in Chrome or Firefox and go to **Network** to find some problems and look if the code isn't loading.

Solution remove the space between filename and `.png` extension.

https://developer.chrome.com/devtools

Comment: So I made a new folder on Desktop named html5 and moved my image and test.html in the same folder and ran it, but no luck. same result :(. The names used are fine.

Comment: Are you sure that your filename is really correct? It's really a png file and not a jpeg for example? Use another image to test it.

Comment: i used another image and saved it as .jpg and it worked. Why not a .png image??

Comment: Try another png perhaps its an png with animation channel for example. http://fc04.deviantart.net/fs71/f/2010/227/4/6/PNG_Test_by_Destron23.png  try this for example.

Comment: Ok it worked :). An extra space was present after Pacman and .png. Thanks Stony

Comment: @user3138373 you should have a look at the FAQ how to accept an answers and the possibilities here on Stackoverflow.

Answer (score -1):

Try not closing the  tag and adding height and width of the image.

```
<img src="Pacman.png" alt="Pacman Ghost" style="width:100px;height:100px" >
```

Also check if the filename is correct. It might not be able to find your Pacman.png. Try to use an absolute link if possible.

**Edit:** Absolute path with ubuntu:

```
<img src="/home/(your user name)/Desktop/Pacman.png" alt="Pacman Ghost" style="width:100px;height:100px" >
```